# Регулярное выражение на доменный адрес (получить протокол и домен первого и/или второго и/или третьго и т.д.)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно получить из https://example.com/same/erere/ вот это https://example.com с помощью регулярного выражения причём не известно какой адрес будет

Comment: Шел 2018 год. Домен из url до сих пор выковыривали регулярками...

Answer (score 3):

Вашу задачу не нужно решать регулярками. В PHP есть специальные функции для парсинга URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

Выдаст:

```
array(8) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(8) "hostname"
  ["port"]=>
  int(9090)
  ["user"]=>
  string(8) "username"
  ["pass"]=>
  string(8) "password"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(9) "arg=value"
  ["fragment"]=>
  string(6) "anchor"
}
string(4) "http"
string(8) "username"
string(8) "password"
string(8) "hostname"
int(9090)
string(5) "/path"
string(9) "arg=value"
string(6) "anchor"
```

Вам же нужен PHP_URL_SCHEME и PHP_URL_HOST

Да-да, я прекрасно понимаю, что вы просили именно регулярками и вам дали ответы именно на регулярки. Но нужно понимать, что [регулярные выражения](https://xkcd.ru/208/) - это как правило зло и некоторые задачи нужно решать без их помощи, это -- как раз такой случай.

Comment: Хочу дополнить, что parse_url не выполняет валидацию URL и потому имеет смысл предварительно проверить через `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);`

Comment: @Мелкий Правильное и очень хорошее дополнение. Набрёл на этот вопрос в очереди проверок, так что не стал расписывать подробно. Спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

Чуть-чуть отредактировал **ваш** **же** ответ, добавив к нему распознавание **http** и **https**.

Вот собственно и **ответ**:

```
preg_match_all('/(http|https):\/\/(.*?)\/', 'https://example.com/same/erere/', $matches);
```

Также рекомендую **[regex101](https://regex101.com/)** для создания или дебага регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/https:\/\/(.*?)\//', 'https://example.com/same/erere/', $matches);

echo "<pre>";
  print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```